# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined - Gatsby SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby

I'm pulling my hair out over this, I understand what the error signifies but just can't get to the bottom of it.

{headerStyles.title} just keeps on kicking up this TypeError. As far as I'm aware, I have all the module syntax correct.

**header.js**

```
import headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

return (
    <div className={headerStyles.header}>
      <h1>
        <Link className={headerStyles.title} to="/">
          {data.site.siteMetaData.title}
        </Link>
      </h1>
    </div>
)
```

**header.module.scss**

```
.title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: What version of `react-scripts` are you running? Keep in mind that CSS modules only is supported by `react-script@2.0.0` and higher. And is the path for the header.module.scss 100% correct?

Comment: Are your paths correct?

Comment: @idkwhatsgoingon Paths are 100% correct as they're in the same directory and I'm running `react-scripts@4.0.1`. I'm running `sass@1.29.0` as `node-sass` was recently deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `import * as headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"`

Comment: I'm baffled. It used to work for me as OP described. I've just started a new project and having to use this method. What changed?

Comment: @freethebees - any luck with this? running into the same problem, no idea what is going on

Comment: @fullStackChris Yeah. It all came about in the change from Gatsby 2 to Gatsby 3. It was in the [release notes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules). I'm not a regular Gatsby user though, so I missed that and assumed some copy-pasta from an old project would work ok. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution if you couldn't find the issue. Just use the ".scss" file, not the ".module.scss". Import the scss file and use the class name as like it is.

```
return (
<div className={"header"}>
  <h1>
    <Link className={"title"} to="/">
      {data.site.siteMetaData.title}
    </Link>
  </h1>
</div>
```

)